# Javascript doesn't like 16.1 value?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is JavaScript’s Math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

Funny question, but why at 16.1 javascript become "crazy"? :)

[Code](http://jsfiddle.net/sP4YF/) :

```
var value1=16.1;
var value2=16.2;

console.log(value1 * 1000);
console.log(value2 * 1000);
```

Output :

```
16100.000000000002
16200
```

Why?

Comment: This questions comes out now and then but Stack Overflow's search engine makes it impossible to find the precise dupes :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because javascript casts everything to a double internally.  As a result, all calculations pick up some noise due to floating point inaccuracy:  [Floating point inaccuracy examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100490/floating-point-inaccuracy-examples)

One way to fix this issue, is to just round down to the nearest int after all intermediate calculations.

[Answer Copy From Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486234/mysterious-calculation-error-when-multiply-by-100/6486253#6486253)

Answer (score 1):

It's not a javascript problem, it's a problem related to any programming language using floating point numbers, see

[Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-javascripts-math-broken)

for explanation of the root problem and for some useful workarounds too.